# Why would this line throw a syntax error in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I am getting a syntax error on this line of code in Python (tried in both 2.7.5 and 3.3)
Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
if (ctx.bytes[0] = t + len) < t:
```

Appreciate any help!

Added 10/31/2013: My problem has stemmed from the fact that an online converter probably converted the code badly from C to Python.  So I REALLY need help on how to convert this program to Python (will prefer 3, but 2 is fine).  I need a lot of help with this because I don't 1) understand fully what the C code is doing and 2) I am still very new to Python! So help is appreciated!!!  The full C source is posted at Pastebin here:  http://pastebin.com/JTT1srSb.

Comment: The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`, and `=` is a statement so you can't use it in `if`.

Comment: I actually am trying to convert a C program to Python and tried an online converter, but I am not sure it worked right.  The function (in C) is at this link: http://pastebin.com/xCbrPcsY

Comment: do you know that python has md5 built in ?

Answer (score 4):

Python won't let you use a single equals sign (assignment operator) within a conditional expression, unlike languages like C. Instead, try doing the following:

```
ctx.bytes[0] = t + len

if ctx.bytes[0] < t:
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C, the assignment operator does not return any value and so can not be used in expressions. Python's `if` statement's condition has to be an expression. You can replace your code with:

```
ctx.bytes[0] = t + len
if len:
```

PS: You don't need to put brackets around the condition of an if statement in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ctx.bytes[0] = t + len) < t
```

You are using assignment operator (`=`) in the boolean expression, which is not allowed in python.

Comment: ok.  Appreciate the insight.  Got the original code I am working with as a C file (not C++) and trying to convert it to Python. It is a short program, but obviously I need a lot of help to get it done.

Comment: @MikeNeedham See [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102593/tips-on-converting-a-c-program-to-pure-python).

Comment: Thanks Ramchandra.  Still need a lot of help deciding how to write this code.  I have pasted the full C source of the program I need to convert here: http://pastebin.com/4RxM1whN.  If someone can take a look and give me an idea of the direction I need to go.